# Hide part of image

Tags: image-processing, filter, image-manipulation, jpeg

I have an image in `jpg` format.
I want to apply image effect on a rectangle inside image.
the effect should do something that human could not recognize what is behind the image.
the effect should have the reversibility capability so when someone applying the effect and send me the image I apply another filter on it and get the original picture.

another part of image (whole image except that rectangle (rectangle size and position is known in both filtering and defiltering process)) should not be modified and should be recognizable by human.

an example would be hiding human face in an image in a way other part of image are still visible.

the problem is:

1. image is in jpg form and I am not allowed to change the format, so jpg compression and other issues with jpg format make some troubles.
2. I just get the image and I should apply filter and overwrite it, the source picture should not be stored.
3. which filter should I use? I have some Image processing knowledge and I can use `OpenCV` and `Aforge`. and the effect shouldn't be checkboarding!

Comment: Is the rectangle always positioned in the same spot, or you should also be able to guess what part of the image was encrypted?

Comment: I have the rectangle position and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it need to be a pixel transformation?  Could you just redact the rectangle (turn all pixels to black) and store the original in meta-data in the JPEG?  You could even encrypt it. You would have a perfect version of it, and anyone looking at the image wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: if it is a pixel transformation it will be much better, btw what is metadate in jpeg file and how can i use it? if the scenario you said is possible I can blur the area and store the original in meta date and then restore it, so this is also a very good solution

Comment: I read about meta data in jpeg files and notice your idea is very goof. tnx.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your sequence:

```
1. get jpg
2. transform
3. save jpg
```

It is **not** perfectly reversible, for exactly the reason you mention: jpg is lossy, even at the highest-quality setting.

Comment: I know it is not perfectly reversible, I want something satisfiable.

Comment: @HPT, the problem is that jpeg compression discards information it deems to be not relevant to a viewer. Any scrambling you do to the information in the rectangle is going to make the compression artifacts much worse than they would be in a natural picture.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is apply a permutation between all the pixels of that specific part in your image, you can do the opposite process to get your image back.